# How can i get user input from textbox to use it in my countdown script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi i have a countdown system i want to know how to make it as a variable, this is the script: in secondpage.html

```
<script>

    var message = new Array();
    message[0] = "status: just started";
    message[10] = "status: drinking a coffe";
    message[20] = "status: just finished setting up the database";
    message[30] = "status: brainstorming about the template";
    message[50] = "status: choosing the color scheme";
    message[80] = "status: thinking about the future";
    message[90] = "status: nearly done";
    message[100] = "status: finished";

    jQuery(document).ready(function () {


        function callback() {
            alert("finish");
        }
        $("#flipit").coffeetime({
            /* COUNTDOWN SETTINGS */
            message: message, // the message array with the array keys as percent values
            startYear: 2013,
            startMonth: 8,
            startDay: 1,
            endYear: 2015,
            endMonth: 0,
            endDay: 0,
            soundControlCssClass: 'icon sound margin-top-20  body-google-font',
            messageBoxId: "percent-message",
            callbackFinish: callback,
        });


        $(".flip-title-subheading").html("was created in: " + new Date() + " and we`ll finish after: " + window.endDate);

    });
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(".flip-container").animate({
                "height": 105 + "px"
            }, 1000, "swing");
        }, 1000);
    });
</script>
```

i had solved the start year by putting "new date()", but the problem is with the end date,
i want endYer, endMonth and endDay to be a variables that the user can input them,
the input page pageone.html:

```
Year: <input type="text" name="Year" id="Year" size="4"><br />
    Month: <input type="text" name="Month" id="Month" size="2"><br />
    Day: <input type="text" name="Day" id="Year" size="2"><br />
```

i want these input to be transfer to secondpage.html to use it in the countdown script

please tell me how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're after is some server side code that will take the data submitted by a form on pageone.html and pass it through to secondpage.html when you submit it, which would require something like PHP (or another server side language of your choosing).

This would mean pageone.html would look something like this:

```html
<form method="post" action="secondpage.php">
    Year: <input type="text" name="Year" id="Year" size="4"><br />
    Month: <input type="text" name="Month" id="Month" size="2"><br />
    Day: <input type="text" name="Day" id="Year" size="2"><br />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

...and secondpage.html would become secondpage.php and would look something like this:

```
<?php
$end_year = (int) $_POST['Year'];
$end_month = (int) $_POST['Month'];
$end_day = (int) $_POST['Day'];
?>
```

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

var message = new Array();
message[0] = "status: just started";
message[10] = "status: drinking a coffe";
message[20] = "status: just finished setting up the database";
message[30] = "status: brainstorming about the template";
message[50] = "status: choosing the color scheme";
message[80] = "status: thinking about the future";
message[90] = "status: nearly done";
message[100] = "status: finished";

jQuery(document).ready(function () {


    function callback() {
        alert("finish");
    }
    $("#flipit").coffeetime({
        /* COUNTDOWN SETTINGS */
        message: message, // the message array with the array keys as percent values
        startYear: 2013,
        startMonth: 8,
        startDay: 1,
        endYear: <?php echo $end_year; ?>,
        endMonth: <?php echo $end_month; ?>,
        endDay: <?php echo $end_day; ?>,
        soundControlCssClass: 'icon sound margin-top-20  body-google-font',
        messageBoxId: "percent-message",
        callbackFinish: callback,
    });


    $(".flip-title-subheading").html("was created in: " + new Date() + " and we'll finish after: " + window.endDate);

});
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(".flip-container").animate({
            "height": 105 + "px"
        }, 1000, "swing");
    }, 1000);
});
</script>
```

Note the php tags in the countdown settings section passing through the values set as variables in the PHP at the top of secondpage.php

Hope that helps

Comment: dude thanks very much for the replay, i did what u told me but id doesn't work, i think i put `<?php
$end_year = (int) $_POST['Year'];
$end_month = (int) $_POST['Month'];
$end_day = (int) $_POST['Day'];
?>`  in wrong location where should i put this code?

Comment: That should go at the top of secondpage.php

Comment: If it's still not working, then it could be down to your server environment not being able to deal with php. try putting <?php phpinfo(); ?> at the top of secondpage.php, if you don't see a load of info about your php install, then it's not setup for php, so you may have to get that sorted out first. Alternatively, I've missed something really obvious

Comment: I wanted to check I'd not done anything silly but realised I didn't have any of the HTML from secondpage.php, so obviously couldn't see anything, but the values I put in on pageone.html were being picked up and put into the script, so assuming your server can handle php, then what I suggested should work.

Comment: Thanks very much bro, you did a great job to me, words aren't enough.

Comment: one more thing please, i know the code must be in the top of the page but where? inside <html></html>? or <body></body?

Comment: Ahh, that's the fun bit of PHP, main functionality like that doesn't have to sit inside the html content if you don't want it to. Usually I'd put that stuff right at the top of the page, before any html. This way the PHP will be processed by the server before anything else gets rendered and then any variables you've created can be used later on in the page inline with your HTML